# $X_1, X_2, \dots \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$, $T_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$, find distribution of $N = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I(T_k < t_0)$, $t_0 > 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$; i.e., they have density (for $\beta > 0$)
>   $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}\cdot I(x > 0)\text{.}$$
>
> Denote $T_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$ and find the distribution of $N =
>  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I(T_k < t_0)$, where $t_0 > 0$ is fixed.

I have the solution in front of me, but don't understand the first step. Let $n \geq 0$. Then
$$\mathbb{P}(N \leq n) = \mathbb{P}(T_{n+1}>t_0)\text{.}$$
**Why is this equality true?**

We have, for any $n \geq 0$:
$$\mathbb{P}(N \leq n) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I(T_k < t_0) \leq n\right)\text{.}$$
I tried writing my thoughts after this point, and found myself getting lost in a wad of symbols. Can someone explain why 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I(T_k < t_0) \leq n\right) = \mathbb{P}(T_{n+1}>t_0)\text{?}$$

Comment: $N\le n$ means that there are at most $n$ *arrivals* (=variables $T_k$) before the time $t_0$. This is equivalent to saying that the $(n+1)$th arrival is after the time $t_0$. The distribution is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Perhaps easier to see it by realizing that $P(N = n) = P(T_{n+1} >t_0 \mid T_n \leq t_0)$ and $T_{n+1} = T_n + X_{n+1}$.